# Joomla / JomSocial Registration with LDAP

Tags: joomla, ldap, registration, jomsocial

So far, we have a Joomla website deployed which, among others, have installed the plugin JomSocial. The default Joomla registration process is overriden by that of JomSocial. So far, this is working properly.

The problem comes when trying to integrate the login / registration process with LDAP. For this purpose, I have installed the JMapMyLDAP plugin:

http://shmanic.com/tools/jmapmyldap/documentation.htm

I have been following the documentation for installing the second version as described in the documentation. I have configured the LDAP host properly, and it is connecting to LDAP, as described in the step `Configuring LDAP Settings (Version 2)`

After that, I've been following the step `Setting up the Creation Plug-in (Version 2)`, including modifying the default XML template so that the form fields correspond to the actual names of the fields in the JomSocial registration form (they are different from those in the default Joomla registration).

While the registration proccess is performed correctly, no entry is added to LDAP at all. Moreover, after the registration process is completed, an extra screen is shown, with no styling at all, where the fields 'Name', 'Username', 'Email', 'Password' and 'Verify Password' are requested (they were already requested before). Even if these are fulfilled and sent, the error "Invalid Token" is displayed.

I appreciate any help in order to effectively connect the registration proccess with LDAP.

Regards.

UPDATE 1:

Hi. I update with new information.

So far I'm trying to connect the Joomla registration form instead of the JomSocial one. I'm obtaining the next error:

`An LDAP add operation failed.`

In the debug log I find the next information

```
2014-04-10T14:07:36+00:00       101     Attempting connection to LDAP with host $IP$
2014-04-10T14:07:36+00:00       101     Successfully connected to $IP$. Setting the following parameters: ldapV3
2014-04-10T14:07:36+00:00       101     Successfully connected.
2014-04-10T14:07:36+00:00       101     Attempt to retrieve user distinguished name using '(cn=asd)'  with search.
2014-04-10T14:07:36+00:00       101     Closed connection.
2014-04-10T14:07:36+00:00       101     Attempting connection to LDAP with host $IP$
2014-04-10T14:07:36+00:00       101     Successfully connected to $IP$. Setting the following parameters: ldapV3
2014-04-10T14:07:36+00:00       101     Successfully connected.
2014-04-10T14:07:36+00:00       101     Attempt to retrieve user distinguished name using '(cn=asd)'  with search.
2014-04-10T14:07:36+00:00       12802   An LDAP add operation failed.
2014-04-10T14:07:36+00:00       101     Closed connection.
```